# Pure type systems and let-expressions

Tags: reference-request, type-theory

I can not find any simple and detailed source of how to add non-recursive let-expressions to pure type systems.

The best I found is the [Henk paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1997/01/henk.pdf) by Simon Peyton Jones, but his explanation of this point is very brief.

Can someone link some references about this topic (source code is accepted)?

**EDIT**

The `let` I want to add has the following syntax:

```
let x : T = M in N
```

where `x` is the variable name, `T` is its type, `M` is the expression with which all free occurrences of `x` in expression `N` will be replaced. It can only introduce nested definitions, so recursion is impossible.

In untyped lambda calculus it is syntactic sugar. By analogy it should be equivalent to `(λ(x : T) -> N) M`, but as you know this conversion does not type-check in PTS, so new type rules must be included.

Comment: Although this question is not off topic here, the TCS SE would have a much better expertise answering it :)

Comment: I think you should clarify which kind of "let" you would like to add. In particular, whether it should implicitly create a polymorphic term (à la Hindley-Milner) or whether it only creates a binding for another term, using the same type.

Comment: Thank you. I'm puzzled now -- I thought `(λ(x : T) -> N) M` type checked, even in PTS. What's the problem there? If `M` has type `T` it should work. Both `M` and `N` seem to be typed in the same context wrt `let` or its desugaring. Are you considering the case where the lambda builds a $\prod$ type which is outside the current PTS? Then, I might understand...

Comment: @chi The value of `M` is not known when typechecking `(λ(x : T) -> N)` which makes a big different with `let x = M in N`. Think of e.g. `let x = 1 in refl : x = 1`. `\(x : Nat) -> refl : x = 1` would be ill-typed.

Comment: @gallais I see, thanks. I would have expected that to fail type checking in both cases, but Coq accepts it. I guess the typing rule substitutes the local definition at a certain point before checking `refl : x = 1`.

Comment: @chi Yep. There's a special typechecking rule for let-bindings in Coq: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html#inference-let It works hand-in-hand with delta-reduction: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html#delta-reduction

Answer (score 4):

There is a definite dearth of literature on how to add let bindings to PTSes or dependently typed systems, though I do seem to recall this reference:

Paolo Severi, [Pure Type Systems with Definitions.](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/1874317/9313025.pdf)

From a theoretical perspective, you want to have the intuitive rule:

$$\frac{\Gamma\vdash t[M/x] : A[M/x]\qquad \Gamma\vdash M:B}{\Gamma\vdash\mbox{let}\ x :B :=M\ \mbox{in}\ t\ :\ A} $$

But this doesn't help explain much about how to perform type checking and conversion, which is a quite subtle subject.